# Using Firebase and Firestore as complementary backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I have developed my own backend for user registration and user authentication. All this info is stored in a database in which I have full control. No passwords are saved (I am using jwt) and there are two tables:

- One for users
- One for privacy settings

I need to have one more table (let's say a posts) that needs to provide real-time features (streams). For this, the simplest solution I can think of is Firestore as it supports real-time and also sync with mobile app.

My question is: as I want to have as much control as possible, especially when it comes to user data (name, lastname etc) is it a good idea to share my app's backend between my own solution and Firestore for one table?

How I am thinking of it working is as follows:

- User with id 123 creates a post
- The post data is stored in Firestore with creator_id = 123
- My front-end fetches the data and also queries my own db to find the name and surname of this person with the id '123' in order to show it to the front-end.

Do you think it is a viable, efficient and scalable solution? Or should I just dump everything in Firestore?

Please note that at this moment, developing my own real-time solution is not possible, so Firestore is the single solution.

Comment: This question is asking for opinions and that's off topic for SO, so don't be surprised if the question is closed. Also, it sounds like an interesting project but without understanding the entire use case, it would be challenging for us to even pose an accurate answer. So, put everything in Firebase and try it, and if it doesn't work, change that.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the architecture is a good idea for your app, only you can determine. But it's quite common to combine Firestore (or the Realtime Database, the other database in Firebase) with existing backend infrastructure.

Typical things to consider in such a combined setup:

- Does Firestore also need to know about your users? For example, if you want to ensure that each user can only read their own data from Firestore, you will need to sign the users in with Firebase too. To learn how to do that, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [creating a custom auth provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).
- What it main copy of your data, which all other copies are derived from. It sounds like your existing DB is the main copy, but it's good to be explicit about this for every piece of data.

Comment: Thank you. I have already implemented custom authentication. My whole point is about efficiency, complexity and performance.